# Unable to connect to a remote database

Tags: mysql, ssh, connection, mongodb

I'm playing with [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/). I have a good deal of experience with MySQL and was using something called [Sequel Pro](http://www.sequelpro.com/) to connect to remote databases. I'm now trying [MongoHub](http://mongohub.todayclose.com/) but can't seem to get it to connect to the remote database.

I tried a basic SSH tunnel

```
ssh -f user@remotehost.com -L 9009:remotehost.com:27017 -N
```

But this didn't work. How do other DB management tools use a ssh login to provide a connection to the database that doesn't have an open port? Is this something I could setup by myself (via a tunnel or something else)?

Comment: To talk to anything past a firewall you need an open port, what do you mean by something that doesn't have an open port?

Comment: What connection string are you using to connect to the database? Can you connect to it with the command line mongo client? Can you telnet to localhost 9009?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's what I do to get to my remotely mysql server (I've got mysql restricted to localhost only):

```
ssh -fNL 9999:localhost:3306 myuser@myremotemachine
```

To describe it,

- **-f** puts it in the background
- **-N** tells ssh there is no command to execute
- **-L** 9999:localhost:3306 tells to bind the local port **9999** to **3306** remotely.

Then I use MySQL Query browser and tell it to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 9999

So I suppose you could try:

```
ssh -fNL 9009:localhost:27017 myuser@myremotemachine
```